# How to specify a read receipt for MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am using [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) from Google Apps Script to send emails.  When I send an email, I want to be able to track to see if the email was opened or not.  This email account is a G Suite account and Email Read Receipts is set to "Allow email read receipts to be sent to any email address."

With MailApp, how do I specify to send the read receipt for the email?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is not possible with the **MailApp** class. The only option I thought it would be possible is by using the method `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`. However, this method does not include any option to request for a read receipt as how you can see under the **Advanced parameters** explanation.

I also checked the **GMAIL API** service and there is no option to do this as well. The help center article **[here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1385059?hl=en)**, explains this is available inside the gmail web UI and after several testing, I found out this is not possible via API.

In summary, by using apps script or the Gmail API is not possible to achieve this. The only thing that comes to my mind right now, is to implement a system in which you will include a unique image in the message and track for when the image is loaded. When the image is loaded, that means the message has been read. I have no idea how to implement such solution but I know is possible.

Comment: I had looked at the different sendMail()s and did not find any option, as well.  The Adv Gmail Service is a REST API for managing a Gmail acct.  It looks like I can't use it to do what I want.  When I look at the support link, it gives me some additional information.  It lead me to Enable Read Receipts which I have done and Read Receipts are dependent on the user to send the message back.  Is there something that can be embedded into the email message where it does not involve the user?  Appreciate your input.

Comment: @user6213384 I have updated the answer. Sorry for providing partial information before. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: No need for an apology.  Some how products like [Streak](https://www.streak.com/) and [Yet Another Mail Merge](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/mail-merge) are able to track emails and using GMail.  I wonder how it is implemented?