# Gmail Api Mail Read Reciept

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

Is there a way to way to get **read receipt** of sent mail?
Like which mail is **read** and which one is **unread**?
Using **google apis Rest**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you check the [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/) you cannot find any guides here that can achieve this. I found here a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615362/how-to-specify-a-read-receipt-for-mailapp) that try to use Apps Script in achieving this, but it seems that the Apps Script is also not applicable. I suggest you to file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/) about this if you still want to do it with the Gmail api.

Answer (score 2):

Read Receipt is no available in current version of google mail api.
provide third party solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As of now Read reciept is not available.
but you can always write custom code to implement task.